# Android: Problems with OAuthRequest's send() method

Tags: android, oauth, yelp

We're currently working on an app that interfaces with the yelp API. We have a method that is intended to get our response body. It works when we call it from a main function however, it breaks down when we try to call it in our activity with the emulator (even when using the exact same arguments). This is the method:

```
public String search(String term, double latitude, double longitude) {
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search");
    request.addQuerystringParameter("term", term);
    request.addQuerystringParameter("ll", latitude + "," + longitude);
    this.service.signRequest(this.accessToken, request);

    //the line where Android seem to be having problem?
    Response response = request.send();
    return response.getBody();
}
```

The app will get to "Response response = request.send();" and then simply terminate with calling the return statement when run through the emulator, but works perfectly fine when run through a main method. Anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you try thread? or try AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to add permissions to my manifest. Problem solved.